# Applet Stand alone issue

Tags: java, applet

I attempted to make an applet program I have Stand alone by adding in:

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("StartingPoint");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    StartingPoint sp = new StartingPoint();
    frame.getContentPane().add(sp);
    sp.init();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    sp.start();
    }
```

Right after my public class. When running as just the applet this does nothing, but when Running it as an application it runs as a very small, nearly flat box aside from the heading, and when manually resized, the screen is blank other then the backround color.
Any idea what may cause this?

I have also noticed, each time I resize the frame, what is on it freezes,as if a screen shot of what should happen, and when the screen is resized to nearly full screen I can see at the tip top of the screen a sliver of what should be moving.

Comment: Does the applet require parameters, or the typical applet methods like `showDocument(..)`?  If so it will require an applet stub & context.  Agree with @MadProgrammer that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to say, that dropping an applet into a frame is a really bad idea.  You are better off writing the application contents into a separate container (such as `JPanel`) and adding that to your applet or frame - IMHO.

From the Java Docs...

> Window#pack
>
> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method.
>
> If the window and/or its owner are not displayable yet, both of them
>   are made displayable before calculating the preferred size. The Window
>   is validated after its size is being calculated.

This would suggest that your applet needs to provide a `preferredSize` if you wish to use `pack`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the size of the `JFrame`:

```
frame.setSize(500, 400);
```

It sounds as if you are overriding the `paint()` method. If so, you will need to call

```
super.paint(g);
```

to repaint all child components of the applet container on resize.

Comment: I added the Set size. But where would I call the super.paint(g);?

Comment: yes in the class that the main is in as an override, then again in many other classes.

Comment: Your `paint` method does not look right. I don't see any custom painting there. Every component should be able to paint itself. Never call `paint` directly BTW.

Comment: each component can, but I I have it looped in the update method to initiate paint, which loops to custom paint in each component.